# Creating promotional material for a book by splicing only selected parts together

Tags: self-publishing, ebook

I'm writing a nonfiction technical ebook which I intend to sell for a month or two before it's published. For the purpose of promotion during the presale period I have to create some promotional material.

Would it be ok if the promotional pages are modified in such a way that I add only parts of different chapters and splice them together in a shorter version, but in a way that is contextually sound? That would also mean that the promotional pages would not be structurally the same as in the final product.

I dont know if that is accepted on most ebook platforms or if it's a common practice.

Comment: Speaking as a representative of "most ebook platforms" I can tell you... Well... Nothing, actually, since I'm not such. Look to see what other authors have done. Try to figure out which of those have achieved the purposes for which you are writing.